# How to make SQL JOIN return only one row with most recent status code?

Tags: sql, sqlite

The following SQL statement:

```
SELECT f.id, 
       f.front, 
       f.back, 
       h.statusChangedIdCode, 
       h.whenCreated,
       h.historyIdCode 
FROM dpod_site_flashcards AS f 
   JOIN dpod_site_historyItems AS h ON f.id = h.itemId 
WHERE f.id = 216 
  AND historyIdCode = 'statusChanged' 
ORDER BY h.whenCreated
```

gives me the following output. **How do I change it so that it returns only one line which has the most recent statusChangedIdCode?**

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
SELECT f.id, 
       f.front, 
       f.back, 
       h.statusChangedIdCode, 
       h.whenCreated,
       h.historyIdCode 
FROM dpod_site_flashcards AS f 
   JOIN dpod_site_historyItems AS h ON f.id = h.itemId 
WHERE f.id = 216 
  AND h.historyIdCode = 'statusChanged' 
  AND h.whenCreated = (select max(whenCreated)
                       from dpod_site_historyItems h2
                       where h2.itemId = h.itemId
                         and h2.historyIdCode = 'statusChanged')
ORDER BY h.whenCreated
```

or if you have a modern DBMS supporting windowing functions:

```
SELECT f.id, 
       f.front, 
       f.back, 
       h.statusChangedIdCode, 
       h.whenCreated,
       h.historyIdCode 
FROM dpod_site_flashcards AS f 
   JOIN (
     select itemid, 
            historyIdCode,
            whenCreated,
            statusChangedIdCode,
            row_number() over (partition by itemid order by whenCreated desc) as rn 
     from dpod_site_historyItems 
     where historyIdCode = 'statusChanged' 
   ) h ON f.id = h.itemId AND h.rn = 1
WHERE f.id = 216 
ORDER BY h.whenCreated
```

Both cases also work when you select rows for more than one `dpod_site_flashcards.id` which the LIMIT solution would not do.

Comment: I think you forgot to filter on `historyIdCode` in your subselect.

Comment: @Neil: that is done in the outer query. But you have a point. It probably should be done in the inner query

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I'm concerned that the `MAX(whenCreated)` will pick a date for a row whose `historyIdCode` is not `'statusChanged'`.

Answer (score 3):

Tried this?

```
SELECT f.id, f.front, f.back, h.statusChangedIdCode, MAX(h.whenCreated), h.historyIdCode 
FROM dpod_site_flashcards AS f 
JOIN dpod_site_historyItems AS h ON f.id=h.itemId 
WHERE f.id = 216 AND historyIdCode='statusChanged' 
GROUP BY f.id, f.front, f.back, h.statusChangedIdCode, h.historyIdCode
```

-EDIT

Oops, thanks [@Gordon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035/gordon-linoff), didn't read the requirements closely enough.  Here is some [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9d46a/3) that should do the job.

Here is the sniplet of the correct code -- include this in your WHERE clause:

```
h.whenCreated = (select max(whenCreated)
   from dpod_site_historyItems h2
   where h2.itemId = h.itemId)
```

Comment: This doesn't return the right answer.  The question is looking for one row, not a separate row for each statusChangedIDCode.  Why do such incorrect answers get upvotes?

Comment: Thanks -- read that too quickly, see edits, posted link to revised sql.

Comment: . . I more than understand getting the question wrong (lots of experience here).  What I don't understand are the upvotes.  As a rule, I'm not going to downvote someone because of a misunderstanding, only for egregious use of SQL.

Comment: Why not include your SQLFiddle statement in this answer?

Answer (score 2):

This is based on @itchy's answer.  The best answer depends on the database.

Some databases support `limit`, so the answer is:

```
SELECT f.id, 
       f.front, 
       f.back, 
       h.statusChangedIdCode, 
       h.whenCreated,
       h.historyIdCode 
FROM dpod_site_flashcards AS f 
   JOIN dpod_site_historyItems AS h ON f.id = h.itemId 
WHERE f.id = 216 
  AND historyIdCode = 'statusChanged' 
ORDER BY h.whenCreated
limit 1
```

SQL Server and Sybase support `top`, resulting in:

```
SELECT top 1 f.id, 
       f.front, 
       f.back, 
       h.statusChangedIdCode, 
       h.whenCreated,
       h.historyIdCode 
FROM dpod_site_flashcards AS f 
   JOIN dpod_site_historyItems AS h ON f.id = h.itemId 
WHERE f.id = 216 
  AND historyIdCode = 'statusChanged' 
ORDER BY h.whenCreated
```

Oracle uses rownum, but you need a subquery:

```
select * from (SELECT f.id, 
       f.front, 
       f.back, 
       h.statusChangedIdCode, 
       h.whenCreated,
       h.historyIdCode 
FROM dpod_site_flashcards AS f 
   JOIN dpod_site_historyItems AS h ON f.id = h.itemId 
WHERE f.id = 216 
  AND historyIdCode = 'statusChanged' 
ORDER BY h.whenCreated
) t
where rownum = 1
```

DB2 uses fetch_first:

```
SELECT f.id, 
       f.front, 
       f.back, 
       h.statusChangedIdCode, 
       h.whenCreated,
       h.historyIdCode 
FROM dpod_site_flashcards AS f 
   JOIN dpod_site_historyItems AS h ON f.id = h.itemId 
WHERE f.id = 216 
  AND historyIdCode = 'statusChanged' 
ORDER BY h.whenCreated
fetch first 1 row only
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use MySQL, change the end to: `ORDER BY h.whenCreated DESC LIMIT 1`

Comment: That might be a database specific solution, it certaiinly won't work in most databases. Please postw hat database it would work on.

Comment: Depending on the database, the syntax might be `SELECT top 1 . . . ` or `where rownum = 1`.